# SELECT Query doesn't work MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I can't seem to make my query work. When I use $sth->execute(); I do get a reading, yet is pretty worthless for my goal as far as I know. If I use query, nothing shows up. Keep in mind that I'm a beginner when it comes to coding. Also, this is a school project and nothing more.

I don't know why the first line of code won't be implemented so look at the row below as part of the code:

```
$team1 = $_POST['teamname'];
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT odds1 FROM odds WHERE :team1=team1");
$sth->bindParam(':team1', $team1);
$sth->query();
$values = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                 
echo $values[odds1];
```

Comment: isnt it `WHERE team1= ':team1'`?

Comment: The variable should be on the right-hand-side of the equal to sign. "SELECT odds1 FROM odds WHERE team1=:team1"

Comment: and also  $values[0]["odds1"] (but of course u should check it first);

Comment: @PrashanthBenny you don't need the quotes with pdo

Comment: @PrashanthBenny It's kind of concerning that your incorrect recommendation got so many upvotes. PDO has never worked that way. Placeholders have never worked that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should be crashing with errors, so if you're wondering why it "doesn't work" the first place to check is your error log. PHP will output all kinds of warnings and errors there that help with your debugging, so if you don't know where that is now's the time to find out.

The technical fix is that `query()` is the wrong method to run on a statement handle. Instead you call `execute()`:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT odds1 FROM odds WHERE :team1=team1");
$sth->bindParam(':team1', $team1);
$sth->execute();
```

You can actually minimize this:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT odds1 FROM odds WHERE :team1=team1");
$sth->execute([ ':team1' => $team1 ]);
```

This is because `execute` can take an array of parameters.

The order of arguments in SQL is conventionally `column=?` but you can do this in either order, MySQL's comparison is bi-directional. It'll make your code more conventional if you write your query as:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT odds1 FROM odds WHERE team1=:team1");
```

Now having a column name like `odds1` and `team1` is usually a sign that you've violated the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A proper normal form would have a one-to-many relationship between one record and others.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Thanks for cleaning that up.

Comment: appreciated :-)

Comment: It's a relation between two entities of the same type. Trying to normalize it, you would get a *1-to-2* relation - And that would violate the *Zero, One or Infinity Rule*. But good answer anyway.

Comment: If it's a relationship between two entities, that's either a one-to-one (e.g. x and y are related, but only one y per x and vice-versa) or a one-to-many. If "many" turns out to be two in all practical cases that's fine. There is no "two" in relational theory.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo $values[odds1];
```

To

```
echo "<p>Results:<pre>".print_r($values[odds1],true)."</pre></p>\n";
```